# Remove last td from a tr

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add a new td upon mouse over of a tr. I tried the following way, which is removing the complete tr. I have a simple table as shown below.

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Position</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tfoot>
      <tr>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Position</th>
      </tr>
   </tfoot>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
         <td>System Architect</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Garrett Winters</td>
         <td>Accountant</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Ashton Cox</td>
         <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

I am trying to add a new td upon mouse over on a any of the tr. Below is my jQuery Code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var trIndex = null;
    $('#example tr td').hover(function() {
        //on mouse over
        trIndex = $(this).parent().append("<td>Hello</td>"); //id='test'
    }, function() {
        //on mouse release
        $(trIndex).remove();//this is removing the complete tr which was previously mouse overed
    });
});
```

I have tried the following way, which has no effect.

```
$(trIndex).remove("td:last-child");
```

How to remove the td?

Comment: `$(this).parent().find("td:last").remove();` instead of `$(trIndex).remove();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

because `$(this).parent().append("<td>Hello</td>");` returns the tr element so `trIndex` is referring to the `tr` element

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#example tr').hover(function () {
        $(this).append("<td>Hello</td>"); //id='test'
    }, function () {
        $(this).find('td:last-child').remove();
    });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example tr').hover(function() {
    $(this).append("<td>Hello</td>"); //id='test'
  }, function() {
    $(this).find('td:last-child').remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett Winters</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ashton Cox</td>
      <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#id th:last-child, #id td:last-child").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

please try

```
$('#example tr:last').remove();
```

Comment: This is totally incorrect. There is big differnce between removing last `tr` and removing last `td` in hovered `tr`.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are binding event to td and not tr. Try this. Working plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/cRRcUITRpYcvhZA6htu0?p=preview)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var trIndex = null;
  $('#example tr').hover(function() {
    //on mouse over
    trIndex = $(this).append("<td>Hello</td>"); //id='test'
    console.log(trIndex);
  }, function() {
    //on mouse release
    $(trIndex).find('td:last-of-type').remove(); //this is removing the complete tr which was previously mouse overed
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `trIndex` will point to the tr which is hovered.so from there you need to find the last `tr`.Please find the below snippet.working fine.

> Code Snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var trIndex = null;
    $('#example tr td').hover(function() {
        //on mouse over
        trIndex = $(this).parent().append("<td>Hello</td>"); //id='test'
    }, function() {
        //on mouse release
        $(trIndex).find('td:last').remove();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Position</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tfoot>
      <tr>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Position</th>
      </tr>
   </tfoot>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
         <td>System Architect</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Garrett Winters</td>
         <td>Accountant</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Ashton Cox</td>
         <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```